# How to correctly format dates in Power BI

Tags: date, powerbi, format

I am connecting to a stored procedure in SQLServer, from the data source the column `AnioMes` arrives as follows:

[image]

Once loaded in PowerBI it has the same format as follows:

[image]

I would like to give the correct format separating the year and the month in new columns, someone can give me an orientation on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an import model, just convert the number to a date in PowerQuery.  For beginners in Power Query [Add Column From Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-add-column-from-example) is your friend.

If it's DirectQuery or Import, you should have a calendar table (aka a Date Dimension) in SQL Server that you can join this column to, and bring that into your model.

Comment: How can I convert this field to date?